# I'm trying to get a div element to follow my mouse (javascript), but it keeps glitching

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I have been trying to get a div element to follow my mouse with javascript, but it keeps glitching to the upper left hand corner. Here is my code:
HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="circle"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#77dd77;
}
div{
  position:absolute;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  height:35px;
  width:35px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let circle = document.getElementById('circle');
  let left = e.offsetX;
  let top = e.offsetY;
  circle.style.left = left + 'px';
  circle.style.top = top + 'px';
});
```

I'm still having a hard time figuring out if the error is occuring in the CSS or JavaScript. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `e.pageY` and `e.pageX` instead of `e.offset...` because `page...` is relative to the document as a whole. `offset...` is relative to the parent container (in this case `body`) and since `body` has no height (since it's child has a position of absolute) the mouse detection for `offset...` is inconsistent.

```js
let circle = document.getElementById('circle');

const onMouseMove = (e) =>{
  circle.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  circle.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#77dd77;
}
#circle{
  position:absolute;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  height:35px;
  width:35px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="circle"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! in five minutes I will accept this as an answer. What is the difference between offset... and page...?

Comment: @HoneyPoop Of course. I updated the answer to explain the difference. Basically `page...` works relative to the whole document, whereas `offset...` only works relative to the parent container. In this case, the parent container (`body`) had virtually no height since it's child was positioned `absolute`, therefore it could not accurately determine the offset, resulting in the glitch. `page...` is much more reliable in this case.

Comment: @MattCroak would this be possible to do inside a containing div as opposed to the whole document?